# Python: Average over bins

Tags: python, numpy

I created bins for age and have a productivity factor (Prod). Now I want to group the bins and calculate average over Prod. So that in the end I have age categories with their average productivity.

```
     bin        Prod
1   (40, 50]    72.920192
2   (30, 40]    51.582848
3   (20, 30]    17.478928
4   (20, 30]    49.205143
6   (50, 60]    38.416232
7   (50, 60]    57.782620
9   (50, 60]    56.718825
10  (50, 60]    75.326448
11  (20, 30]    75.327148
12  (40, 50]    106.354800
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.groupby('bin')['Prod'].mean()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output as dataframe again:

```
df.groupby('bin').Prod.mean().reset_index()
```

output:

```
       bin       Prod
0  (20,30]  47.337073
1  (30,40]  51.582848
2  (40,50]  89.637496
3  (50,60]  57.061031
```